# Cannot load __log_finite from libm.so.6 with ctypes

Tags: python, shared-libraries, ctypes

I'm trying to load the function `__log_finite` from `libm.so.6` using `ctypes`.

If I run nm on the library I can see that the symbol refers to an indirect function (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html).

```
nm -gD libm.so.6 | grep __log_finite
000000000002c520 i __log_finite
```

When I try to load this function with ctypes from python I get an error that suggests that the symbol is not defined:

```
import ctypes
lib = types.CDLL("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6")
func = lib.__log_finite
```

raises:

```
AttributeError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: undefined symbol: __log_finite
```

If I try to load any other non-indirect function, I do not get this error:

```
nm -gD libm.so.6 | grep roundevenl
000000000001cc20 W roundevenl
```

```
func = lib.roundevenl
print(func)
```

outputs

```
<_FuncPtr object at 0x7fbea6820400>
```

I'm wondering what is going on here and the reason for this behavior. Is this related to __log_finite or to all the indirect functions?

NOTE: this issue does not seem related to the indirect function but to the finite suffix: I'm not able to load any `*_finite` function (e.g., `__acos_finite`, `__expf_finite`...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is due to the removal of various _finite functions definitions in glibc > 2.31.  In my case, the problem was resolved by adding `-fno-finite-math-only` compilation flag, as suggested [here](https://github.com/Ardour/ardour/commit/83cd796a474f74)