# symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: __pow_finite

Tags: python, clang, shared-libraries, glibc

I am trying to run [a software](https://github.com/scottransom/presto/tree/master) that ran flawlessly before upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, but now I receive the error

```
symbol lookup error: /Softwares/presto/lib/libpresto.so: undefined symbol: __pow_finite
```

On [another stack page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72363848/cannot-load-log-finite-from-libm-so-6-with-ctypes) it suggests to

```
nm -gD libpresto.so | grep __pow_finite
             U __pow_finite
```

On [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62334452/fast-math-cause-undefined-reference-to-pow-finite) it says it might be a CLANG bug. I quickly checked, and it doesn't seem to show a `.comment` file or a similar log file where such info are reported. How do I know by which CLANG version I have compiled the software? If it is a < 10 version should I reinstall CLANG first and then re-`make`?

Comment: There were some changes in glibc 2.31. IIRC All the `__xyz_finite` functions did not disappear, but they are now only aliases to the improved functions in the math library. Or something like that. Re-compiling the C code should fix it.

Comment: @VPfB thanks. If you write an answer (possibly for the other question in my post as well) and instruct on how to re-compile I will accept your answer/bounty it.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not know the full answer. I work mainly with Python (not clang, etc.) and saw your question only because it is tagged `[python]`. By chance I have read somewhere about these `_finite` symbols so I wrote a comment. I guess following the installation instructions should work.